# Java program to create concentric rectangles and ovals?

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java and working on a program that creates a concentric series of rectangles and ovals. I want the user to be able to input their own height and width, and the figure will automatically be proportional to JPanel (which I have done) and  to remain centered, while following the line along the left diagonal of JPanel. (The issue I'm having).

This is my code so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    int height = 100;
    int width = 200;
    int x = (getWidth()-width)/2;
    int y = (getHeight()-height)/2;
    graphic.drawRect(x+i*(x/3),y+i*(y/6), width - i * (width/4),height - i * (height/4));
    graphic.drawOval(x+i*(x/3),y+i*(y/6), width - i * (width/4),height - i * (height/4));
}
```

Which gives me this figure:

[image]

I'm going to take care of the user input after I get it working for at least this individual case.
Any help would be appreciated!

How the picture should look:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeACE.png)

Comment: This gives me proportional concentric shapes, but they don't remain centered.

Comment: This question is unclear. Should the circles be concentric, or should they follow a diagonal line? Maybe you should also show a picture how it _should_ look.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're incrementing and changing the center of your oval/rectangle each time you increment your for loop counter.

```
graphic.drawRect(x+i*(x/3),y+i*(y/6), width - i * (width/4),height - i * (height/4));
graphic.drawOval(x+i*(x/3),y+i*(y/6), width - i * (width/4),height - i * (height/4));
```

should become something like

```
graphic.drawRect(width / 2, height / 2, width - i * (width/4),height - i * (height/4));
graphic.drawOval(width / 2, height / 2, width - i * (width/4),height - i * (height/4));
```

---

Also a second issue I didn't notice before are these lines,

```
int x = (getWidth()-width)/2;
int y = (getHeight()-height)/2;
```

where, if I guessed what getWidth() and getHeight() do correctly, you're always setting x and y to 0 because you're saying something like (width - width) / 2.

Comment: I tried that at the start, instead of being centered all of my figures start from the top left corner and then get bigger, I can't post any more pictures or links unfortunately so I can't show it to you.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a better explanation of what's going on along with what I think it is you're trying to do. Essentially two things were happening, the first being the first two parameters of the draw methods are the center points of your shapes (which was why I originally had it set to x & y, but what I missed was the way you are calculating those starting points before makes your x & y always 0.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the path of getWidth() is int javax.swing.JComponent.getWidth() which is giving me the size of Jpanel (I believe) I outputted the results of x and y and I'm actually getting 42 for x and 80 for y. The figure from your code above actually off centers my box, and the figures within start from the top left corner. Sorry if I'm not being clear enough and I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've actually figured it out, editing my getRect and getOval functions below:

```
graphic.drawRect(x+(i*(width/8)),y+(i*(height/8)), width - i * (width/4),height - i * (height/4));
graphic.drawOval(x+(i*(width/8)),y+(i*(height/8)),width - i * (width/4),height - i * (height/4));
```

including the width and height in the calculation for x and y made it porpotional to the amount the width and height were changing, so that the figure remained centered. Now to pretty it up and try to cut out some calculations.